# Get events from multiple partitions using azure-event-hubs-python?

Tags: python-2.7, azure, amqp, azure-eventhub

I was following instruction given here https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/tree/master.

But I am not sure about how to use multiple partitions.

I tried doing something like this

```
for partition in range(0, 4):
    EventHubClient(ADDRESS).subscribe(MyReceiver(str(partition)), CONSUMER_GROUP, str(partition), OFFSET).run()
```

But it only creates receiver for Partition 0 and listen to it only. Is there any simple way to create multiple receiver that listen to event on different partition.

I also tried using

```
for partition in range(0, 4):
    EventHubClient(ADDRESS).subscribe(MyReceiver(str(partition)), CONSUMER_GROUP, str(partition), OFFSET).run_daemon()
```

It created multiple receiver, but I did not actually got the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run method is blocking. Events are delivered to the callback of MyReceiver. To subscribe to multiple partitions, try the following,

```
EventHubClient(ADDRESS).subscribe(MyReceiver("0"), CONSUMER_GROUP, "0", OFFSET)
    .subscribe(MyReceiver("1"), CONSUMER_GROUP, "1", OFFSET)
    .subscribe(MyReceiver("2"), CONSUMER_GROUP, "2", OFFSET)
    .subscribe(MyReceiver("3"), CONSUMER_GROUP, "3", OFFSET)
    .run()
```

Method run_daemon runs the client on a dedicated thread so that application can call Receiver.receive method to get messages when they are needed. You can subscribe to multiple partitions in the same way.

Comment: Do you know If we can getRuntimeInformation from EventHubClient. I want the number of partitions setup for eventhub.